# Getting an error when looping

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm writing some code that will pulls URLS from a text file and then check to see if they load or not. The code I have is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'timeout'

Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"
browser = Watir::Browser.new

File.open('pl.txt').each_line do |urls|
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(10) do
      browser.goto(urls.chomp)
      if browser.text.include? "server"
        puts 'here the page didnt' 
      else
        puts 'here site was found'
        File.open('works.txt', 'a') { |f| f.puts urls }
      end
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts e
  end
end

browser.close
```

The thing is though I get the error:

```
execution expired
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.9.4/lib/firewatir/jssh_socket.rb:19:in `const_get': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.9.4/lib/firewatir/jssh_socket.rb:19:in `js_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.9.4/lib/firewatir/firefox.rb:303:in `open_window'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.9.4/lib/firewatir/firefox.rb:94:in `get_window_number'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/firewatir-1.9.4/lib/firewatir/firefox.rb:103:in `goto'
    from samplecodestack.rb:17
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
    from samplecodestack.rb:16
    from samplecodestack.rb:13:in `each_line'
    from samplecodestack.rb:13
```

Anyone know how to get it working?

Comment: If all you want to do is check for still valid URLs, you probably should just use `Net::HTTP` and issue a `HEAD` request. Checking for the word "server" in the site's body will exclude a lot of sites that actually did load properly.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but some of the sites the servers are down, and the script just ends up throwing out an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use net/http and handle the timeouts too.

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"
File.open('pl.txt').each_line do |urls|
    uri = URI.parse(urls.chomp)
    begin
        response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
    rescue Exception=> e
        puts e.message
        puts "did not load!"
    end
end
```

I had trouble following your stack trace but it seems to be on your goto statement.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is check the URL's using net/http or a gem like http-party would be a lot faster and simpler since you can just get the HTTP status code, if it's 2xx or 3xx(a redirect) then it's likely good, if it's 4xx or 5xx then you have some kind of error.  Watir would be more appropriate for actual functional testing

Answer (score 0):

`execution expired` is the error that occurs when the block for the `Timeout::timeout` is exceeded. Note that the timeout is checking that its entire block is completed in the specified time. Given the line number errors, I am guessing that the URL being loaded took close to 10 seconds and then the text check timed out.

I assume you really only mean for the timeout to occur if the page takes longer than 10 seconds to load, rather than the entire test taking 10 seconds to finish. So you should move the if statement out of the Timeout block:

```
File.open('pl.txt').each_line do |urls|
  begin
    Timeout::timeout(10) do
      browser.goto(urls.chomp)
    end
    if browser.text.include? "server"
      puts 'here the page didnt' 
    else
      puts 'here site was found'
      File.open('works.txt', 'a') { |f| f.puts urls }
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts 'here the page took too long to load'
    puts e
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I went with the net/http thing in the end but you taught me a thing or two, didn't know about the Timeout thing doing the whole block, thought it just checked the site and that was it.